# Relating decidable, undecidable, recognizable, co-recognizable, unrecognizable, countable and uncountable languages

Tags: formal-languages

I went through a lot of texts and came up with following diagram to summarize the relation between decidable, undecidable, recognizable, co-recognizable, unrecognizable, countable and uncountable. Am I correct with it?

[image]

Note that this makes unrecognizable proper subset of undecidable. Also countable and uncountable makes up whole space, that is, there is no language which is neither countable nor un-countable.

In tabular format:
[image]

**Edit 1**

I dont know if we can classify every language as countable or uncountable and if there is no third possibility. I guess there should be another language class, possibly named **enumerable**, which will have languages having injective function from themselves to real numbers (sort of "well ordered"). **Countable** languages have injective function from themselves to natural numbers (sort of "strictly well ordered"). With this definition will Countable $\subset$ Enumerable ? Also we will then require **un-enumerable** class (instead of uncountable class), which will neither have injective function to natural numbers nor to real numbers (sort of "un ordered"). Something like this:

[image]

Am I sounding stupid here?

**Edit 2**

So if thoughts in edit 1 is correct, definitions of various terms will be:

[image]

**Note:**

- **O** entry in the table means may or may not hold the property.
- Counting procedure means given string present in language, it can eventually confirm that string was indeed part of language, but may not be able to confirm if the string does not belong to the language.
- Membership procedure means given string, it can confirm whether the string belongs to language or not.

**PS:** I have not given second thought to first table after edits. It might not align with thoughts in edits.

Comment: I did that because the formal-languages tag is present on both sites. Also, because there might be people present member of one site but not of other. I want to get help of both of them. Also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/377092) meta says, cross posting is not bad, just that I may try to customize two posts according to different site, which I accept I did not do. But I feel the topic really overlap two subjects, maths and computer science.

Comment: But did you customize your question? Did you very *very* clearly pointed out that you posted this simultaneously on *both* sites? Currently you're asking people to do work that might have already been done on another site. That is an awful abuse of the precious free time you're asking people to put into reading your question and thinking about it.

Comment: Was busy in having thoughts I put in edits. Will try to customize, but honestly I dont know what exact customization I will have to do, given the topic really overlaps in both subjects.

Comment: We expect you to think about your question *before* posting it. In particular, if you feel like cross-posting **simultaneously** is appropriate, we expect that you've put thought into how to customize the question for each site. Seeing how you're not currently at the stage of doing so, I will save everyone time and migrate your question to CS where it can be merged with your other question. In the future, if you want to refer to the meta.SE site as a vindication of your behavior, please make sure that you're actually up to the expected standards of the exceptions to the rule.